# Zero number paper at the beginning and the end of my algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, algpseudocode

I am using {algorithm}, {algorithmic} and {algpseudocode} packages to write an algorithm on latex put there zero number (0:) appear at the beginning and the end of the pseudo code:

```
\begin{algorithm}[!htbp]
\begin{algorithmic}
\begin{ALC@g}
\If { ['part\_neg'] tag is existing at PoS\_Tags[sentence]}
\begin{ALC@g}
\STATE NFR\_Score[sentence] = +1
\STATE NFR\_CF [sentence] = Maximum (NFR\_CF [sentence], 0. 8266)
\end{ALC@g}
\EndIf
\end{ALC@g}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image: The code output]

update: using the first answer solution I had the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't load `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode` together and don't mix the syntax: `\If` is `algpseudocode` and `\STATE` is `algorithmic`.

There is no need to use `ALG@c` (and it does harm).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!htbp]
\begin{algorithmic}
\IF {['part\_neg'] tag is existing at PoS\_Tags[sentence]}
\STATE NFR\_Score[sentence] = +1
\STATE NFR\_CF [sentence] = Maximum (NFR\_CF [sentence], 0. 8266)
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, @egreg your solution worked, but my code is longer than I posted. 
I have if .. else if statements. I change it from \If { }... \ElsIf{ }  to \IF ... \ELSIF{} but it does not work and gives me errors also "0=" appear at the end of the pseudo-code!

Comment: @Eng.sh Sorry, but I cannot guess what your input is. Please ask a new question.

Comment: I wrote another question. Please see it hear  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650804/nested-if-doesnt-work-on-my-latex-algorithm-code