# nested if doesn't work on my latex algorithm code

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I am trying to write a nested if pseudo code on latex put the following error is appearing:

> LaTeX Error: Command \NOT already defined.

```
\begin{algorithm}[!htbp]
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE \textbf{Step 5}: Compare each sentence Scores and CFs to determine the class it belong to:
\begin{ALC@g}
\IF {(FR\_Score[sentence] $>$ NFR\_Score[sentence])} 
\STATE Class[Sentence] = FR  
\ELSIF{(FR\_Score[sentence] $<$ NFR\_Score[sentence]) }
\STATE Class [Sentence] = NFR 
\ELSIF {(FR\_Score[sentence] == NFR\_Score[sentence])} 
\begin{ALC@g}
\IF{(FR\_CF[sentence] $>$ NFR\_CF[sentence])} 

\STATE Class[Sentence] = FR  

\ELSIF {(FR\_CF[sentence] $<$ NFR\_CF[sentence])} 

\STATE Class[Sentence] = NFR  

\ELSIF {(FR\_CF[sentence]  == NFR\_CF[sentence])} 

\STATE Class [Sentence] = Nan
\end{ALC@g}
\end{ALC@g}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

> update after removing \begin{ALC@g} ..\end{ALC@g} from the code and adding   \ENDIF the problem is solved but a 0= symbol is steel appear at the end of the algorithm
> [image]

Comment: Why are you using `\begin{ALG@g}` and `\end{ALG@g}`? I told you not to.

Comment: because without using it here latex doesn't give me the required alignment. in the other parts of the code I removed it there's no problem. but here because if and if else statement doesn't work well I don't remove it

Comment: See answer (and in the previous question of yours I removed those bits and added `\ENDIF`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering where you found `\begin{ALC@g}` and `\end{ALC@g}` documented. You want to close the `\IF` statements with `\ENDIF`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!htbp]
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE \textbf{Step 5}: Compare each sentence Scores and CFs to determine the class it belong to:
\IF {(FR\_Score[sentence] $>$ NFR\_Score[sentence])} 
  \STATE Class[Sentence] = FR  
\ELSIF{(FR\_Score[sentence] $<$ NFR\_Score[sentence]) }
  \STATE Class [Sentence] = NFR 
\ELSIF {(FR\_Score[sentence] == NFR\_Score[sentence])} 
  \IF{(FR\_CF[sentence] $>$ NFR\_CF[sentence])} 
    \STATE Class[Sentence] = FR  
  \ELSIF {(FR\_CF[sentence] $<$ NFR\_CF[sentence])} 
    \STATE Class[Sentence] = NFR  
  \ELSIF {(FR\_CF[sentence]  == NFR\_CF[sentence])} 
    \STATE Class [Sentence] = Nan
  \ENDIF
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg ! sorry for bothering you. could you see the update, please

Comment: @Eng.sh Do you see =0 in my image? No. So, please, add a complete (but minimal) document, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that shows the issue.

Comment: Finally solved the problem. I am just remove \usepackage{algpseudocode} from the code. Thank you very much @egreg